# implementing Static object on a moving scene

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

How to implement an 'menu' that seems like stuck to it's position? Here with stuck I meant to say either `scene` is moving or still it remain on it's on position. Which gives feel like it's on it's place. I am implementing it by moving it with scrolling scene, it works but behave absurdly, 'sometimes'.

Here is the code how am I creating `menu`:

```
resetPosition =[CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"position.png"
                                      selectedImage:@"position_over.png" 
                                      disabledImage:@"disabled.png"
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(reset)]; 
resetPosition.position =ccp(400, 300);
myresetMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:resetPosition, nil];
myresetMenu.position = ccp(0,0);
[[self parent] addChild:myresetMenu z:10];  
[resetPosition setIsEnabled:NO];
```

And now code for moving the scene(when user trying to scroll the scene). Also I have moved the menu with `scene`, so it gives the effect that the menu is still with the `scene`:

```
if([touchArray count]==1)//scroll
        {

            UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
            CGPoint location = [myTouch locationInView:[myTouch view]];
            moveLocation1 = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
            float diffX = beginLocation1.x - moveLocation1.x;
            float diffY = beginLocation1.y - moveLocation1.y;   

            //NAVIGATION TOWARDS X AND Y WhenEver and how ever you want         
            if (abs(diffX) > abs(diffY))
            {
                CCLOG(@"yScrlFlag=%d",yScrlFlag);
                if(diffX > 0)
                {
                    xScrlFlag=1;
                    [self.parent runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:round(-(-3112-self.parent.position.x)/650)
                                                               position:ccp((-3112-self.position.x),self.parent.position.y)]];
                    [resetPosition setIsEnabled:YES];
                    [resetPosition runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:round(-(-3112-self.parent.position.x)/650) 
                                                                 position:ccp((3112+self.position.x+400),resetPosition.position.y)]];
                }
                else
                {
                    xScrlFlag=0;                        
                    [self.parent runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:(-self.parent.position.x/650) 
                                                               position:ccp(0,self.parent.position.y)]];
                    //[resetPosition setIsEnabled:YES];
                    [resetPosition runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:(-self.parent.position.x/650) 
                                                                 position:ccp(400,resetPosition.position.y)]];
                }
            }
            else
            {                       
                if(diffY < 0)
                {
                    yScrlFlag=1;
                    CCLOG(@"\n nodePosition.x=%f \n nodePosition.y=%f",nodePosition.x,nodePosition.y);
                    [self.parent runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:(-(-300-self.parent.position.y)/650) 
                                                               position:ccp(self.parent.position.x,(-self.position.y))]];
                    //[self.parent runAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:(-(-300-self.parent.position.y)/650)
                    //                                         position:ccp(self.parent.position.x, -diffY)]];
                    [resetPosition setIsEnabled:YES];
                    //[resetPosition runAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:round(-(-300-self.parent.position.x)/650) 
                    //                                           position:ccp(resetPosition.position.x, (self.parent.position.y))]];
                }
                else
                {   
                    yScrlFlag=0;
                    [self.parent runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:(-(-300-self.parent.position.y)/650) 
                                                               position:ccp(self.parent.position.x,0)]];
                    //[resetPosition runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:round(-(-300-self.parent.position.x)/650) 
                    //                                           position:ccp(resetPosition.position.x,300)]];
                }   
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a bit of trouble with this a while back.  I had been trying to have UI elements that did not get lost when the camera moved.  What I ended up doing was adding a CCParallaxNode as a child and setting the parallax ratio to ccp(0.0, 0.0) on everything I put on it.  That way the scene can move around but my UI layer stays in place.  I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it, but I'm a dirty hack kind of programmer :)

Comment: What ever and how ever yo have did it, you did it to the best. thanks ya... :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify how you create your menus and what are you doing with them, so my answer is pretty general...

The right approach to this, for me is having a UI layer where you put all your UI stuff (menus, buttons, etc.) and that you treat differently from your other, game layers. In other words, you give your UI layer a fixed position and then don't apply any actions or any other kind of transformations to it. It should stay pretty static this way.

Cocos2d offers its own classes to manage `CCMenu`, `CCMenuItem`, and `CCLabel` that allow you to build you UI easily. But, if you prefer, you could also try and integrate `UIKit` objects. Have a look at [`CCUIViewWrapper`](http://www.google.es/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBUQFjAA&url=http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6889&ei=YRP3TZ-kJoGbhQet652oDA&usg=AFQjCNGGZpHKREpq7XcMwWI2B1v8WERhEQ), if you really need it.

EDIT:

The idea about having a UI layer is the following in more detail:

1. you have a root layer acting as a container of all your layers;
2. one of those layers is the "game layer", which is pretty much what you have now;
3. another is the "ui layer";
4. touches and any kind of transformations are only applied to the "game layer", which move within the root layer without affecting the "ui layer".

There is a nice tutorial about this in "[Learn Game Development with Cocos2D](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/)" by Steffen Itterheim. This book is fantastic if you want to learn several nifty approaches to your cocos2d game. The tutorial I am talking about is available in code form on Steffen's site. You can dowload it from [this page](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/book-learn-cocos2d/) and look into chapter 5 "Scene and Layers" example, specifically starting from ScenesAndLayers04, where you will find the 'MultiLayerScene.h/m` classes.

Comment: Thanks for the response, please go through  the code i have mentioned in edit, And as i am moving my scene while scrolling, so will it be any profitable to add any layer?

Comment: I edited my answer adding more detail, and a reference to a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

@sergio has the right idea.

With your code though. Have it in a layer all to itself and then on the touch action move it like you are already and just reset its position when you take the action to bring the menu back up again.

Comment: MMmmhhhh, what I'm doing is near to right, and as `menu` is already being used sergio's suggestion also in implementation(as per I get his solution, correct me if I didn't), but many times it behave absurdly that's the real problem.